# Getting JSON from PHP MySQL connection

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

There are many examples of this on StackOverflow, but I can't see the error in my code. I followed a few tutorials and copied some code off this forum and it still errors bugs out.

My `CREATE TABLE` query:

```
CREATE TABLE `e1_ENGLISH` (
    `entry_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `words_e1` char(30) NOT NULL,
    `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `phonetic_e1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`entry_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=42 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php
// establish connection
// mysqli contect (host, user, pass, db)
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","androidapp","password","myDB");

// check for connection success
if(!$conn) {
  die("Error, could not connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// build query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM e1_ENGLISH";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); // fetch data

// convert result to array
$resArray = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //$resArray[] = $row;
    $resArray[] = utf8_encode($row);
}

// display result
echo json_encode($resArray);

// close connection
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

The output I get (with `utf8_encode`):

```
[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]
```

I get a blank screen with just `$resArray[] = $row;`

I am new to PHP, MySQL data, and webservers. Any mistakes you can spot? Additionally, I dont have a script or anything, this is straight PHP.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: instead of `fetch_assoc` either use `fetch_array`  or `$resArray[] = utf8_encode($row['put_column_name_here']);// repeat it in while loop for all column` and check

Comment: Ok, will try. What exactly is the difference with `fetch_assoc` and the other `fetch_` methods? I have trouble understanding why some examples use it.

Comment: `fetch_assoc` gave you associative array so you need to use column names there. while `fetch_array()` give you both combo (numeric+associative). you can get only numeric too. check on google for that

Comment: Somebody's downvoting all answers. How about some comments as to the reason(s).

Comment: @Anant That's not really practical. Sometimes someone else has made the same comment you were going to make, there's no need to repeat it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `utf8_encode()` has to be a string, you can't call it on an array. You need to loop over `$row` calling it on each element.

```
$resArray = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    foreach ($row as &$val) {
        $val = utf8_encode($val);
    }
    $resArray[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have shown me the data in JSON format.

Comment: Hey @Barmar, do you know I could see this `bo?` in the browser while I see this `boθ` in the database? it seems like I still have UTF-8 issues. My database and tables are all `utf8mb4`.

Comment: Make sure you have the proper encoding specified in the `<head>`.

Comment: Beyond that, I'm not sure. charset issues often confuse me as well.

Comment: I don't have HTML wrapping my PHP code. Is there another head you are referring?

Comment: I'm talking about the web page that has the AJAX call that uses this JSON.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm new to webserver and webapp stuff. I just a PHP file that I refer in the URL and it prints directly to the browser. It's literally just a PHP file on the server.

Comment: Why are you printing JSON to the browser? If that's what you want to do, you need to put an HTML wrapper around it so you can specify the character set.

Comment: Or send `header("Content-type: application/json")` before echoing. Then the browser will know that it's JSON, and I think it will do the right thing.

Comment: I was doing that so an app I'm building could parse the data. But I will wrap it with HTML if thats recommended.

Comment: You shouldn't do that for the real app, but if you're just looking at the JSON with a browser you may need it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to fetch like this by record on an array and json_encode the array where name and last_name are the names of your rows in your database

```
            $res_array = array();

            while($row = $result->mysqli_fetch_assoc()) {
                $single_record = array(     
                    "NAME_U_WANT1" => $row['NAME'],
                    "NAME_U_WANT2" => $row['LAST_NAME'],
                );
                array_push($res_array, $single_record);
            }

        return json_encode($res_array);
```

as you see you have to loop their rows

Answer (score 2):

`utf8_encode()` takes a string.  Encode each array element with `array_map()`:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $resArray[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
}
echo json_encode($resArray);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks but I get a 500 Error from the server. What could conflict with that line?

Comment: Nothing, you must have other issues.